# mysql code Is there any method to solve this ? substr field column

Tags: php, mysql, substr

Is there any method to solve this problem ?
in mysql column field date is value as timestamp and i want to fetch all row date which has specific value as format Y-mm ( 2016-05 )?
please help me i am stacking in this problem, Is it possible ?

```
select * from article where postby = 'admin' AND substr(`date`,0,7) = '2016-05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try '[date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)' mysql function:

```
select * from article where postby = 'admin' AND date_format(`date`,'%Y-%m') = '2016-05'
```

Comment: wow accept ... this method work very great.. thank sir. have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

try to CAST it first, if you have to use SUBSTR

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE postby = 'admin' 
AND SUBSTR(CAST(`date` AS CHAR(10)),0,7) = '2016-05'
```